# Matrix equality (|BA| = x|A|)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A = (a_{ij})$ , a 3x3 matrix ($A ≠ 0$)  and it is multiplied with the matrix

$B =\begin{bmatrix}0&3&0\\1&0&0\\7&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

so, if i do $ |B * A| $, we should have something like this,

***$|B*A| = x*|A|$***

Can someone show me how do you find this x?

Comment: Parse the two cases: 1) $|A|=0$, 2) $|A|\neq0$.

Comment: @kabenyuk A ≠ 0

Comment: We are talking about the determinant $A$. If $|A|=0$, then then this equation holds for any $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach is to understand what multiplying by $B$ on the left does to the matrix. The first row of $BA$ will be $3$ times the second row of $A$, the second row of $BA$ will be the first row of $A$ and the third row of $BA$ will be the third row of $A$ plus $7$ times the first row of A. So what we did to $A$ was multiply the second row by $3$, swich it with the first row, then add $7$ times the first row to the third row. The impact on the determinant was to multiply it by $3$, then by $-1$ and then nothing. In the end we just multiplied the deteminant by $-3$, i.e. $x=-3$.

Comment: You can also just use that $det(BA)=det(B)det(A)$.

Comment: Please refrain from answering "do it for me" questions.